# Looking to undelete an answer

Tags: support, deleted-questions

How does one get an answer undeleted?  [My answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17599/salaried-employee-not-being-paid-what-steps-can-i-take/17600#17600) was deleted, and I have modified it to respond to the comment.  What else need be done to undelete it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bringing it up here on meta is a good start. Flagging the post for moderator attention is another option.

Normally, it would take three votes from users with the delete privelege to undelete a deleted answer, but since one of the users who voted to delete in this case was a moderator, it will take a moderator to undelete.

Since you've expanded the answer, I've gone ahead and undeleted it.

Comment: Thanks, jim! Appreciated